# Create a VPN across diffrent public networks

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ip, drac

I have a bunch of 10 iDrac servers, distributed globally across different datacenters with public IPs. There are no firewalls for these servers. How can I bring them into a single network, so that all these servers can be accessed only via a bastion server running in AWS?

The catch here is,

1. IDRAC doesn't allow to install VPN or any form of software.
2. IDRAC supports Ip filtering.

The Primary Goal is to prevent the compromise of the IDRAC servers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also: https://serverfault.com/q/504069/37681

Comment: @HBruijn Even the link doesn't answer exactly, how to secure the IDRAC servers.

Comment: I think you will need a proxy in front of the Dell servers. You can then secure the proxy servers, setup a VPN, etc. I would not connect these cards directly to the Internet.